# Wagtail Ecommerce site

Tags: python, django, wagtail

would it be possible to build a shopping cart and stripe payment system on top of Wagtail by overriding serve() and placing the following views information inside? The following views.py and urls.py are parts of my ecommerce site that I would like to build into my wagtail site. I'm just pretty confused, because i'm used to working with urls.py and views.py. Sounds a whole lot easier than trying to do this in wagtail.

Edit: I currently have a blog site that uses Wagtail, but to add a payment processing system and purchasable content I am just going to create a completely seperate django application and run vanilla django without wagtail on it that links to a subdomain.

Example of a Views.py

```
def paymentMethod(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'checkout/payment_method.html',
    )

def get_user_pending_order(request):
    # get order for the correct user
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    order = Order.objects.filter(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)
    if order.exists():
        # get the only order in the list of filtered orders
        return order[0]
    return 0


def add_to_cart(request, **kwargs):
    #get the user Profile
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)

    #filter products for id
    product = Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('item_id', "")).first()

    #check if the user already owns the product
    if product in request.user.user_profile.merchandise.all():
        messages.info(request, "You already own this product")
        return redirect(reverse('product_list'))
    #create OrderItem of the selected product
    order_item, status = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
    #create order associate with the user
    user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)
    user_order.items.add(order_item)
    if status:
        #generate a reference code
        user_order.ref_code = generate_order_id()
        user_order.save()

    #show confirmataion message and redirect to same page
    messages.info(request, "item added to cart")
    #return redirect(reverse('product_list'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

@login_required
def delete_from_cart(request, item_id):
    item_to_delete = OrderItem.objects.filter(pk=item_id)
    if item_to_delete.exists():
        item_to_delete[0].delete()
        messages.info(request, "Item has been removed from shopping cart")
    return redirect(reverse('checkout:order_summary'))

@login_required
def order_details(request, **kwargs):
    count = OrderItem.objects.all().count()
    existing_order = get_user_pending_order(request)
    context = {
        'order': existing_order,
        'count': count
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout/order_summary.html', context)


#class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
#    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
#    slug_field = 'username'
#    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'

@login_required
def checkout(request):

    count = OrderItem.objects.all().count()
    existing_order = get_user_pending_order(request)

    #stripe
    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    customer_id = request.user.user_stripe.stripe_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        print (token)
                # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
        # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
        try:

            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=999,
                currency='usd',

                description='Example charge',
                source=token,

            )
            return redirect(reverse('checkout:update_records',
                        kwargs={
                            'token': token
                        })
                    )
        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            message.info(request, "Your card has been declined.")


    context = {
        'order': existing_order,
        'publishKey': publishKey,
        'count': count
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout/checkout.html', context)


def update_transaction_records(request, token):
  # get the order being processed
    order_to_purchase = get_user_pending_order(request)

    # update the placed order
    order_to_purchase.is_ordered=True
    order_to_purchase.date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now()
    order_to_purchase.save()

    # get all items in the order - generates a queryset
    order_items = order_to_purchase.items.all()

    # update order items
    order_items.update(is_ordered=True, date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now())
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    #Shopping Cart
    url(r'^payment-method/$', views.paymentMethod, name='payment-method'),
    url(r'^add-to-cart/(?P<item_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    url(r'^order-summary/$', order_details, name='order_summary'),
    url(r'^success/$', success, name='purchase_success'),
    url(r'^item/(?P<item_id>[-\w]+)/delete/$', delete_from_cart, name='delete_item'),
    url(r'^checkout/$', checkout, name='checkout'),
    #url(r'^payment/(?P<order_id>[-\w]+)/update/$', process_payment, name='process_payment'),
     url(r'^update-transaction/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$', update_transaction_records,
        name='update_records')


    #url(r'^tip/create/$', views.TipCreate.as_view(), name='tip_create'),

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You don't need to override Wagtail's `serve` - just include your Django URL patterns in the top-level `urls.py` *before* the `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls))` line so that they take precedence over Wagtail's catch-all pattern.